# An application of Stone-Weierstrass to the fractional heat kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let us consider $$p_t^{(n+2)}(\tilde x) , $$
where $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$, $\tilde x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0, 0) \in \mathbb R^{n+2}$, and $p_t^{(n)}(x)$ is the heat kernel for $(-\Delta)^s$ in $n$ dimensions (see [link for definition](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_heat_equation?)).

It is well known that we can write
$p_t^{(n+2)}(\tilde x)= t^{-(n+2)/2s}k(|\tilde x|/t^{1/(2s)}) $. Is it true that the subalgebra generated by
$$\Big(f_t(r)\Big)_{t>0} \text{ is dense in $C_0(0,\infty)$},$$
where $f_t(r) =r^{n}k(r/t^{1/(2s)})$?

---

I wanted to use the [locally compact version of Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version). But, since the expression of $f_t$ is not explicit, I don't know how to prove that the subalgebra separates points and vanishes nowhere. Also, I'm not sure if the fact that $\tilde x=(x_1,…,x_n,0,0)$ (i.e. the last two coordinates are fixed) is a problem or not.

Comment: I am too lazy to follow links, so I am passing on your question.